# ordenar array multidimensional php

Tags: php, array, classificação, array-multidimensional

Tenho o seguinte array devolvido de um webservice (na imagem identifico o que quero, em baixo o texto para copy paste caso necessário):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Array
(
    [DataTable] => Array
        (
            [ID] => STOCK
            [Line] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => ItemCode
                                            [Value] => 1GADEME010001
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => ItemName
                                            [Value] => Sucata de ferro
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => FrgnName
                                            [Value] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => ItmsGrpCod
                                            [Value] => 112
                                        )
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => ItemCode
                                            [Value] => 1GADEME010001
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => ItemName
                                            [Value] => Armário de ferro
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => FrgnName
                                            [Value] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [FieldID] => ItmsGrpCod
                                            [Value] => 112
                                        )
```

Tendo em conta que o array tem n registos, quero ordenar o array pelo nome, que está sublinhado a vermelho. Tentei usar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada para vê se minha resposta ajuda :)

Comment: Coloca texto ao invés de foto por favor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento já adicionei em código

Answer (score 5):

Bem, acho que eu faria da seguinte forma. Basta usar a função `usort`.

```
usort($dados['dataTable']['lista'], function ($a, $b){ 
  return strcmp($a['fields'][0]['name'], $b['fields'][0]['name']); 
});
```

A função `usort` tem a finalidade de ordenar um `array` de acordo com um `callback` passado pelo usuário (o programador, nesse caso, hehehe).

O `Callback` deve conter dois parâmetros: São os itens, passados de dois em dois, durante a iteração interno que o PHP vai fazer.

De acordo com a comparação é que é feita ali no callback é que o `array` será ordenado.

Você deverá retornar `1`, `-1` ou `0`

Valor 1 - Quando você quer que o elemento `$a` seja o primeiro em relação a `$b`

Valor 0 - Quando a  posição de ordenação permanecer a mesma.

Valor -1 Quando a posição de ordenação de `$b` deverá ser maior que `$a`.

Então, porque usei `strcmp` no retorno?

Essa função, de acordo com o [Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcmp.php):

> Retorna < 0 se str1 é menor do que str2; > 0 se str1 é maior do que str2, e 0 se forem iguais.

Então, observe os valores a seguir para ter uma ideia da nosso exemplo citado acima:

```
strcmp('a', 'b'); // int(-1)

strcmp('b', 'a'); // int(1)

strcmp('b', 'b'); // int(0)
```

Comment: Esse é a logica avançada, e minha é pra leigos :D

Comment: Eu pensei em citar o `sortBy`, do `Collection` do `Laravel`. Mas pelo visto resolveu :)

Comment: Seria interessante comentar que ele compara o índice atual com o próximo, e assim por diante. Praticamente um **Bubble Sort**.

Comment: Eu não sei o que é isso... Pode adicionar a resposta se quiser :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, eu li na internet que o Bubble Sort não era boa opção. Mas no código que colocou, penso que terá um pequeno erro, ao ir buscar a posição do array. Não será $a['fields'][1]['value'] a ir buscar?

Answer (score 3):

A logica pra montar ordenar este tipo de estrutura é montar um array simples que sera ordenado, mantendo as chaves de associação.

```
$dados = array( // DADOS TESTE
    'dataTable' => array(
        'lista' => array(
            0 => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'name' => 'B'
                    )
                )
            ),
            1 => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'name' => 'D'
                    )
                )
            ),
            2 => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'name' => 'C'
                    )
                )
            ),
            3 => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'name' => 'A'
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);

$arraySort = array(); // ARRAY MONO DIMENCIONAL QUE VAI SER ORDENADO 
foreach ($dados['dataTable']['lista'] as $k => $list){
    $arraySort[$k] = $list['fields'][0]['name']; // SET AO DADO RELEVANTE PARA A ORDENAÇÃO
}
asort($arraySort); // ORDENA MANTENDO AS CHAVES

$listaDados = array(); // ARRAY QUE IRA COPIAR "dados", MAS ORDENADO
foreach ($arraySort as $k => $value){
    $listaDados[] = $dados['dataTable']['lista'][$k];   // COPIA OS DADOS DO $k INDICADO
}

$dados['dataTable']['lista'] = $listaDados;

var_dump($dados);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você mesmo possa criar um algoritmo simples para a ordenação, pode até se basear no **Bubble Sort**.

Para isso, use um foreach que percorra todas as chaves do array:

```
foreach ($array as $chave => $valor) {}
```

**Obs:** Possivelmente esse é o modo mais difícil, mas as vezes criar seus próprios métodos em vez de usar sempre funções prontas te ajuda a desenvolver seu raciocínio lógico.

Comment: aceito a sua resposta, mas devia ser um comentário ao post e não uma resposta, porque na verdade não é. O que aconselhou já eu tentei, mas se não tivesse dificuldades não colocava a pergunta. De qualquer maneira obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Foi mal, sou novato por aqui... Se não tiver achado uma solução ainda eu posso tentar criar o método para você. Só preciso da estrutura completa do array com alguns dados de teste e caso consiga solucionar seu problema eu posto como resposta.

Comment: Douglas, sua participação é legal, e sua resposta no caminho certo. se conseguir elaborar um pouco mais a resposta, vai atrair mais votos positivos. Você pode [edit] sua postagem a qualquer momento pra acrescentar mais dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Bacco! Mais tarde tentarei criar um algoritmo bem comentado para ajudar nosso colega e substituirei minha resposta antiga.