# Como ordenar uma Matriz Array em ordem alfabética no PHP?

Tags: php, array, matriz

Possuo uma matriz array nxm que chamarei de `$tabela`.

Essa array possui alguns dados dentro organizados da seguinte forma:

> ```
> | Papel1 | Hora1 | Valor1 | Erro  | B |
> | Papel2 | Hora2 | Valor2 | OK_Ok | A |
> | Papel3 | Hora3 | Valor3 | Falha | C |
> | Papel4 | Hora4 | Valor4 | OK_OK | A |
> ```

Todas os dados da tabela são extraídas de uma tabela `mysql`, exceto a ultima coluna que eu insiro na array baseado em algumas condições.

Minha duvida é, como organizar  em ordem alfabética todas as linhas da array baseando-sena ultima coluna? Teria que retornar dessa forma:

> ```
> | Papel2 | Hora2 | Valor2 | OK_Ok | A |
> | Papel4 | Hora4 | Valor4 | OK_OK | A |
> | Papel1 | Hora1 | Valor1 | Erro  | B |
> | Papel3 | Hora3 | Valor3 | Falha | C |
> ```

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => MIL EUA [1] => 2018-03-05 14:00:13 [3] => 168.99 [2] => 2018-03-05 15:00:11 [4] => 168.99 [5] => Atraso entre os servidores de 59 minutos ) [1] => Array ( [0] => TRIGQQNP [1] => 2018-03-05 14:00:15 [3] => 3800.00 [2] => 2018-03-05 15:00:12 [4] => 3800.00 [5] => Atraso entre os servidores de 59 minutos ) )
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [ordenar array multidimensional php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125607/ordenar-array-multidimensional-php)

Comment: coloca a estrutura das arrays por favor, use print_r ou var_dump em um exemplo relativamente médio de array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["nome_ultimo_campo"], $b["nome_ultimo_campo"]);
}

usort($tabela, "cmp");
```

[Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000005/php-sort-array-by-field) foi levantado algo como o que você precisa.

Comment: No caso do exemplo que eu coloquei acima, qual seria o nome do ultimo campo

Comment: seria o "nome" do último índice..

Comment: Eu não nomeei o indice, devo colocar o número da coluna?

Comment: Acredito que funcione; aí no caso seria sem as aspas (`""`)

Answer (score 2):

Se são colunas que vieram de um banco de dados como você afirmou em:

> Todas os dados da tabela são extraídas de uma tabela mysql

Então antes de inserir no array você poderia já trazer ordenados usando `ORDER by` (`ASC` para crescente e `DESC` para descrente), algo como:

```
SELECT id, nome, foo, bar, ultimacoluna
FROM tabela
WHERE <condica>
LIMIT <limite>
ORDER by ultimacoluna ASC
```

Então no `while` ou `foreach` que provavelmente esta usando para adicionar os itens no novo array eles já estarão em ordem alfabética (podendo depender/variar do sistema de codificação).

No entanto se o problema é outro recomendo que explique o comportamento do código e mostre um exemplo da array usando `print_r` ou `var_dump` para podermos ver de fato como é o formato da sua array de verdade para **só então** possamos sugerir a maneira mais eficiente de verdade para o seu caso especifico.